# Updating old BIOS

Tags: bios, updates

I looked up my BIOS update online and it said it was recommended that I update it using windows 8. I have Windows 10. Will this cause any problems? The latest update for my BIOS was in the 2015 (yes it is quite old). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS will not be an issue for a Windows 10. You can download it to a bootable USB key and update it that way. If you are lucky, it will come as an EXE that you can run to install. I do this on my machines , one of which came initially with Windows 8